# Multiple File Name Match

Tags: php, regex

how would I accomplish the following that are in the comments:

UPDATE: Had wrong file naming convention in comments

```
// Do any of the file names in the list match the file name for this run?
// Full file name is cs1212-42173-TVCS.csv or cs1212-42173-TVWK.csv
$pattern = '/cs'.date('md').'-\d{5}-TVCS\.csv/i';
```

Right now it is only getting the TVCS file name but I need for it to look for both TVCS and for TVWK.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/cs' . date('md') . '-\d{5}-TV(CS|WK)\.csv/i';
```

Comment: It won't match `cs1212-42173.TVWK.csv` specified in the question.

Comment: Just needed it to match TVWK or TVCS. The beginning was just an example.

Comment: @pertrai1 so the file might be `cs1212-42173-TVWK.csv` ?

Comment: Yes I updated my comments in the code above. Jeroen had it right the first time. Sorry about that.